# Probability of drawing an ace and(a king or a queen) among 5 cards drawn from a shuffled standard deck

Tags: probability

Five cards are drawn from a standard deck of 52 cards. What is the probability that there is an ace and a king or a queen among 5 cards.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem?  Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: I think it should be (50 C 3 + 50 C 3)/(52 C 5)

Comment: @ShahzaibAli Put it in the post; not the comments.  Also include *why* you think so.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You want the probability of selecting *at least one from four* aces and *at least one from eight king or queens* when selecting any five from all fifty two cards.

It will be easier, I suggest, to calculate the complement using the principle of inclusion and exclusion (and deMorgan's rule).

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P\big(A\cap(K\cup Q)\big) ~&=~ 1 - \mathsf P\Big(\big(A\cap(K\cup Q)\big)^\complement\Big) \\[1ex] &\hspace{1.5ex}\vdots  \\[1ex] &=~ 1 - \mathsf P\big(A^\complement\big) - \mathsf P\big((K\cup Q)^\complement\big) + \mathsf P\big((A\cup K\cup Q)^\complement\big) \end{align}$$

- $\mathsf P\big(A^\complement\big)$ is the probability of selecting no aces *and* any five from the *forty-eight* other cards when selecting five from all fifty two.
- $\mathsf P\big((K\cup Q)^\complement\big)$ is the probability of selecting no king or queen *and* any five from the *forty-four* other cards when selecting five from all fifty two.
- $\mathsf P\big((A\cup K\cup Q)^\complement\big)$ is the probability of selecting no king, queen, or ace,  *and* any five from the *forty* other cards when selecting five from all fifty two.